# Prepared statements: Memory stays allocated to result set despite we delete it

Tags: mysql, memory-leaks, mysql-connector

In my application (being developed on Windows 8 using MySQL Connector/C++) I am creating prepared statements and deleting them only at the end of the application. But while application is running, I execute queries and delete only result sets.

However, I observed lot of memory remains still allocated and I felt its more than expected. I examine with Visual Leak Detector and to my surprise I found leaks were shown in result set pointer despite I was deleting them appropriately.

So I written demo program that does exactly this. That is create prepared statement, create query, fetch result, delete result (but don't delete the prepared statement at end so that we can see the leaks) and quit.
Here is the demo code `MySQL.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>

#define CPPCONN_LIB_BUILD // We must define this as we are linking mysql connector in static library. It directs build_config.h to not to put __declspec(dllimport) before function declarations.
#include <driver/mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

#include <vld.h> // Visual memory leak detector

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sql::Connection *pConnection = NULL;
    sql::ResultSet *pResultSet = NULL;
    sql::PreparedStatement *pPreparedStatement = NULL;

    sql::Driver *driver = NULL;
    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    pConnection = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "username", "password");

    pConnection->setSchema("MYDB");
    pConnection->setAutoCommit(0);

    sql::ResultSet* pResultSet;

    pPreparedStatement = pConnection->prepareStatement ("select * from mytable where mycolumn > ?"); // mytable has mycolumn that contains 1000 numbers starting from 1

    pPreparedStatement->setInt(1, 1);
    pResultSet= pPreparedStatement->executeQuery();
    int count = pResultSet->rowsCount();
    printf("\nTotal rows found %d", count);

    delete pResultSet;

    // delete pPreparedStatement; // Let's not delete prepared statement to see demo of memory leak in pResultSet
    delete pConnection;

    printf ("\nDone! Quitting...");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is report:

```
Visual Leak Detector Version 2.4RC2 installed.
    Aggregating duplicate leaks.
    Suppressing data dumps.
    Outputting the report to E:\MySQL\memory_leak_report.txt
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 65 at 0x0000000068D87EB0: 8 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x38615834, Count: 1, Total 8 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 4628):
    0x00000000C3EC5630 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\new.cpp (59): MySQLTrials.exe!operator new + 0xA bytes
    0x00000000DF30AEE4 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::util::Singleton<sql::mysql::NativeAPI::LibmysqlStaticProxy>::theInstance + 0x44 bytes
    0x00000000DF306DB1 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::NativeAPI::getCApiHandle + 0x41 bytes
    0x00000000DF2AA5AC (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::NativeAPI::MySQL_NativeDriverWrapper::MySQL_NativeDriverWrapper + 0x5C bytes
    0x00000000DF2AA51D (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::NativeAPI::createNativeDriverWrapper + 0x4D bytes
    0x00000000DF28401B (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::MySQL_Driver + 0x8B bytes
    0x00000000DF28456F (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::get_driver_instance_by_name + 0x18F bytes
    0x00000000DF284681 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::get_driver_instance + 0x21 bytes
    0x00000000DF283E1A (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!get_driver_instance + 0x1A bytes
    e:\mysql\mysql.cpp (22): MySQLTrials.exe!wmain + 0x5 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c (240): MySQLTrials.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x19 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c (164): MySQLTrials.exe!wmainCRTStartup
    0x00000000C1CF167E (File and line number not available): KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x1A bytes
    0x00000000C3EDC3F1 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21 bytes


---------- Block 413 at 0x0000000068D90FF0: 40 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x7614B12C, Count: 1, Total 40 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 4628):
    0x00000000C3EC5630 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\new.cpp (59): MySQLTrials.exe!operator new + 0xA bytes
    0x00000000DF30C576 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::NativeAPI::MySQL_NativeConnectionWrapper::stmt_init + 0x86 bytes
    0x00000000DF28E730 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection::prepareStatement + 0xC0 bytes
    e:\mysql\mysql.cpp (30): MySQLTrials.exe!wmain + 0x30 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c (240): MySQLTrials.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x19 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c (164): MySQLTrials.exe!wmainCRTStartup
    0x00000000C1CF167E (File and line number not available): KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x1A bytes
    0x00000000C3EDC3F1 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21 bytes


---------- Block 241 at 0x0000000068D93910: 16 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x447A29BE, Count: 1, Total 16 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 4628):
    0x00000000C3EC5630 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0 (592): MySQLTrials.exe!std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>::allocate
    0x00000000DF28B052 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy> >::allocate + 0x32 bytes
    0x00000000DF303CA7 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!std::_Deque_alloc<0,std::_Deque_base_types<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64,std::allocator<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64> > >::_Alloc_proxy + 0x37 bytes
    0x00000000DF303991 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!std::_Deque_alloc<0,std::_Deque_base_types<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64,std::allocator<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64> > >::_Deque_alloc<0,std::_Deque_base_types<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64,std + 0x41 bytes
    0x00000000DF303A95 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!std::deque<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64,std::allocator<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64> >::deque<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64,std::allocator<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64> > + 0x35 bytes
    0x00000000DF303ACB (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!std::stack<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64,std::deque<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64,std::allocator<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64> > >::stack<sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugEnterEvent const * __ptr64,std::d + 0x2B bytes
    0x00000000DF302AFE (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_DebugLogger::MySQL_DebugLogger + 0x3E bytes
    0x00000000DF28CD77 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection::MySQL_Connection + 0x227 bytes
    0x00000000DF284184 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::connect + 0xA4 bytes
    e:\mysql\mysql.cpp (23): MySQLTrials.exe!wmain + 0x5B bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c (240): MySQLTrials.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x19 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c (164): MySQLTrials.exe!wmainCRTStartup
    0x00000000C1CF167E (File and line number not available): KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x1A bytes
    0x00000000C3EDC3F1 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21 bytes


---------- Block 483 at 0x0000000068D93960: 11 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x1D599652, Count: 1, Total 11 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 4628):
    0x00000000C3EC5630 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\newaop.cpp (7): MySQLTrials.exe!operator new[]
    0x00000000DF32199C (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_ResultBind::bindResult + 0xA0C bytes
    0x00000000DF321379 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_ResultBind::bindResult + 0x3E9 bytes
    0x00000000DF313F69 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet::MySQL_Prepared_ResultSet + 0x169 bytes
    0x00000000DF2EC0E1 (File and line number not available): MySQLTrials.exe!sql::mysql::MySQL_Prepared_Statement::executeQuery + 0x1F1 bytes
    e:\mysql\mysql.cpp (33): MySQLTrials.exe!wmain + 0x13 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c (240): MySQLTrials.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x19 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crt0.c (164): MySQLTrials.exe!wmainCRTStartup
    0x00000000C1CF167E (File and line number not available): KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x1A bytes
    0x00000000C3EDC3F1 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21 bytes


Visual Leak Detector detected 119 memory leaks (640915 bytes).
Largest number used: 697643 bytes.
Total allocations: 837447 bytes.
Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
```

**Question:**

Why do we see leaks at line MySQL.cpp (23):

```
    pConnection = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "username", "password");
```

and MySQL.cpp (33)

```
    pResultSet= m_pPreparedStatement->executeQuery();
```

despite we delete `pResultSet`and `pConnection`? Why do we need to delete `pPreparedStatement` as well to free result set?

Answer (score 1):

What I can deduce from your statement, you are already freeing the connection with the statement:

```
delete pConnection
```

That means when you initialize the `PreparedStatement` again, you're have to initialize it like:

```
pPreparedStatement = pConnection->prepareStatement(...)
```

Therefore, you don't free the `PreparedStatement` object but only reuse the object. C++ does not have garbage collection by default, and you have to free objects when you no longer need them.

In order to have something close to Java's garbage collection, I'd advice you use either a `shared_ptr` or `scoped_ptr` which will free your memory when your objects are no longer needed.

You can checkout [Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/) for a comprehensive tutorial on how to free memory dynamically. For example:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<sql::Connection> con(driver->connect(host, user,pass));
boost::scoped_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(con->createStatement());
```

That way you don't need to remember to call delete on your objects as memory will be freed when the object is no longer in scope. But you have to include boost libraries.

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
```

Comment: I think the author wants to know why memory for ResultSet is remains allocated even when ResultSet object is deleted. The RAII is no concern here.

Comment: And I want to know it too (=

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious in my opinion that the prepared statement contains the query string which is used to retrieve the resultset, that said it looks clear to me that the prepared statement is in a separate location of memory than the resultset, you can also deduce that from your code:

```
sql::ResultSet *pResultSet = NULL;
sql::PreparedStatement *pPreparedStatement = NULL;
```

therefore when the connection goes out of scope or is released the memory allocated for your prepared statement is still tied to that object containing that query, but since the connection object is freed you have no longer access to that part of your memory, and because it isn't freed like you where supposed to your operating system still has marked that portion of memory flagged as in use, resulting in a memory leak.

Why go through all that trouble finding out why you have free the memory to prevent a memory leak, which seems obvious to me, in stead of just adding one line of code:

```
delete pPreparedStatement.
```

as described in the accompanying documentation, or as I like to do it, encapsulate it in a class (eg. dbConnection) and let de destructor do all the work so you only have to write the statement in one location and can forget it after that. It's easy and clean practice and it teaches to write clean and leak free code.

Adding garbage collection through extra libraries just gets you sloppy and makes for buggy software in my opinion, it's generally not worth the trouble and can give tons of overhead while you really have to add one line of code per object to delete. 
Besides I think that kind of laziness will eventually bite you in the ass when some garbage gets deleted while there is still need for the data it's containing but the garbage collection comes to early, or in fact you let your object go out of scope to soon and you have to find out why your app is constantly crashing in particular situations. 
When you do all the work yourself it may look more troublesome at start but in the end you'll be glad that you can correct that kind of coding errors in seconds in stead of having long antagonizing sessions of bug hunting only to find you somewhere have one small error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Select the version of MySQL you are using and 
SEARCH for 'Prepared SQL Statement Syntax'.

You will find 3 specific activities and Syntax examples
A) PREPARE Syntax
B) EXECUTE Syntax
C) DEALLOCATE Syntax

that may work out better for you than ResultSet object deletion 
and you will likely see your resources have been released, when DEALLOCATE has completed.